# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append' - Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I am attempting to create a new dictionary which will list the species of a tree as well as the DBH for that species. There will be multiple DBH's for each species. It pulls this information from a text file.

The part that creates the first dictionary is working (lists the species and the number for each), but I cannot get it to append the DBH's for each species. I continue to get the error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'. I have searched and searched and tried multiple ways, but cannot get this to work.

```
import string, os.path, os, sys


filepath = "C:\\temp\\rdu_forest1.txt"
data=[]
#Open the text file
myfile=open(filepath,'r')
#Read the text file
myfile.readline() #read the field name line
row = myfile.readline()
count = 0
while row:
    myline = row.split('\t') #Creat a list of the values in this row.  Columns are tab separated.
    #Reads a file with columns: Block Plot  Species DBH MerchHeight
    data.append([float(myline[0]),float(myline[1]),myline[2].rstrip(),float(myline[3].rstrip())]) 
    #rstrip removes white space from the right side
    count = count + 1
    row = myfile.readline()
myfile.close()
mydict={}

mydict2={} #Create an emyty mydict2 here  *********

for row in data:  # for each row
    # create or update a dictionary entry with the current count for that species
    species = row[2]#Species is the third entry in the file
    DBH = row[3] #DBH is the fourth entry in the file 
    if mydict.has_key(species):  #if a dictionary entry already exists for this species
        #Update dict for this species
        cur_entry = mydict[species]
        cur_entry = int(cur_entry)+1
        mydict[species] = cur_entry

        #update mydict2 here  *********
        mydict2[species].append(DBH)

    else:#This is the first dictionary entry for this species
        #Create new dict entry with sums and count for this species
        mydict[species]=1
        mydict2[species]=DBH #Add a new entry to mydict2 here  *********

print mydict
```

Here is the TraceBack

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "E:\Python\16\dictionary.py", line 40, in <module>
    mydict2[species].append(DBH)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Please include the traceback.  That will show the exact line in which the exception is raised.  It will obviously be one of the lines containing `.append()`.  As the error msg says, you'll discover that you're trying to append to a float.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "E:\Python\16\dictionary.py", line 40, in <module>
    mydict2[species].append(DBH)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: So `mydict2[species]` is a float.  Do you expect it to be a float?  You can't append to a float.

Comment: Is this weird? I get no errors at all.

Comment: This is the value of mydict:
{'LOB': 95, 'BE': 1, 'WD': 10, 'WO': 95, 'HK': 19, 'YP': 33, 'POP': 12, 'RB': 3, 'RM': 71, 'ASH': 2, 'LP': 696, 'SLP': 1, 'VP': 1, 'SRW': 2, 'SHL': 17, 'CV': 1, 'RO': 82, 'MPL': 13, 'SP': 1, 'SW': 11, 'MW': 1, 'SL': 21, 'SG': 82}

I want mydict2 to be:
{'LOB': [102, 14, 203], 'BE': [212, 232]...}

The first one shows the species and the number of trees with that species. The second one shows the species and the diameter of each tree for that species. Maybe there is a better way to get those values in there. I am totally new to this concept.

Answer (score 4):

Looks straightforward to me.

```
mydict2[species].append(DBH)
```

Initialized here:

```
mydict2[species]=DBH
```

which comes from here:

```
DBH = row[3]
```

Which comes from here:

```
data.append([float(myline[0]),float(myline[1]),myline[2].rstrip(),float(myline[3].rstrip())])
```

So it's a float. And you can't append to a float,so you get that error.

I think you probably meant to make a list of these DBH's:

```
mydict2[species] = [DBH]
```

Alternatively, you could look into `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict2 = defaultdict(list)
mydict2[species].append(DBH)
```

and you can drop the`if-stmt` -- the code makes a list if there isn't one and always appends.

And I'd also look into using `csv` library for handling your tab-separated file.

---

Here is what I was imagining you would change your code to:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def read_my_data(filepath="C:\\temp\\rdu_forest1.txt"):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as myfile:
        reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter='\t')
        return [
            [float(myline[0]),float(myline[1]),myline[2].rstrip(),float(myline[3].rstrip())]
            for row in reader
        ]

mydict2 = defaultdict(list)

for _, _, species, DBH  in read_my_data():
    mydict2[species].append(DBH)

mydict = {
    k: len(v)
    for k, v in mydict2.iteritems()
}

print mydict
```

Not that I have actually run this or anything. Let me know if you are still having problems with `defaultdict`.

Comment: This is what I get when using the defaultdict:
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'LP': [11.0]})

It should list a lot more species and diameters. I am sure I am using it incorrectly.

Comment: If I use mydict2[species] = [DBH] it only saves one value for the diameter instead of listing all of the values for that species.